# how to get data from asp.net to android?

Tags: c#, android

I have an android program that sends a student ID to a ASP.NET website. The website responds with student info. The request and response are via JSON
but I don't know how to do this to work between asp.net and android.
The android program sends requests. The asp.net gets data from a database and puts it in a datatable, converts to json like this [{},{}].
Please help me with some resources that will work with an android application.
The asp.net code is

```
public string Convert(DataTable row)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
    if (row.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow result in row.Rows)
        {
            jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
            string  idstudent = result["id"].ToString();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("id");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(idstudent);

            string AVG = result["AVG"].ToString();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("AVG");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(AVG);
            string fname = result["fname"].ToString();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("fname");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(fname);
            string date = result["date"].ToString();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("date");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(date);
            string name = result["name"].ToString();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("name");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(name);
            jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
        }

    }
    jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
    jsonWriter.Close();
    sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an intent-filter: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

you can call this like:

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">
```

You could probably Base64 encode your json string and pass it as a URL parameter.

(I pulled this info from here: [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) )